# How to apply geometric series concepts into these numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fibonacci-numbers, ratio

This is a basic level question and it is homework for someone that I am trying to help out. It is indicated as a Fibonacci puzzle. But I am not able to fit the numbers into a general geometric formula. However, solving the question using very simple and basic algebra is not an issue.

"A fruit collector has x number of fruits on Monday. He has to throw (y+2)/2 each day through out the week. y is the beginning number of fruits for a day. On Sunday he is left with just 1 fruit. What was the total fruits he had when he began the week on Monday?"

I literally did 6 calculations to get it done, and it's a shame. I was not able to figure out a common radio at first degree, but a common ratio of second degree after finding the differences between terms. e.g.

T1 = 1, T2 = 4, T3 = 10, T4 = 22
$$4-1 = 3$$  $$10-4 = 6 = 3*2$$
$$22-10 = 12 = 6*2$$
$$46-22 = 24 = 12*2$$

I would appreciate if someone could point me out how to use $$T_n = ar^n-1$$, $$S_n = a(r^n-1)/(r-1)$$ in this scenario.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the given information, the number of fruit $n$ days from the end (where the last day is day $1$) satisfies the formula
$$T_n=T_{n+1}-\frac{T_{n+1}+2}2=\frac{T_{n+1}}2-1\ ,$$
that is,
$$T_{n+1}=2T_n+2\ .$$
A geometric sequence has the form
$$T_{n+1}=rT_n\ ,$$
where $r$ is a fixed number, so this is not a geometric sequence and you cannot use the formulae you have quoted.

...at least, not directly.  However you might notice that the formula can be written as
$$T_{n+1}+2=2(T_n+2)\ ,$$
and so $T_n+2$ **is** a geometric sequence having ratio $r=2$ and initial term $T_1+2=3$.  So a general formula will be
$$T_n+2=3\times2^{n-1}$$
and therefore
$$T_n=3\times2^{n-1}-2\ .$$

Comment: I was infact having the dilema of putting this in right series (Arithmetic, Geometric). On first degree is linear, so it was like arithmetic, then on second degree there's a ratio, then it was like geometric. Anyway thanks for directing me to the right approach. BTW, the 3 line before last, `$$T_{n+1} + 2 = 2(T_n + 2)$$` shouldn't it be `$2(T_n + 1)$$`?

Comment: It's correct - it would be $T_{n+1}=2(T_n+1)$, but $T_{n+1}+2=2(T_n+2)$.

Comment: Anyway your line is correct as the 2 cancels from both sides. So I guess you added the 2 to build up the formula.

Comment: That's correct!